# Installing ros-indigo-desktop-full on ArchLinux: pyqt4-10-common and pyqt4-common are in conflict (pyqt-common). Remove pyqt4-common?

Tags: ros, archlinux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't overcome the above problem. If I start to remove packages to install pyqt4-10, too much other apps would need to be removed (some of them I really need). Does anyone have a solution for this? Manual installation on an other machine didn't really help, the dependency problem strikes me there too.

Cheers
Paul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192417/installing-ros-indigo-desktop-full-on-archlinux:-pyqt4-10-common-and-pyqt4-common-are-in-conflict-(pyqt-common).-remove-pyqt4-common?/) by [poseidon](https://answers.ros.org/users/20168/poseidon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `pyqt4-10` package was made because of this problem: https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/issues/13

Until this is resolved, we need to keep this old version of the `pyqt` packages (or well, until this breaks other stuff). Normally, you don't need to remove other packages, and if pacman complains when you want to downgrade `pyqt` packages, you can always remove the official `pyqt` packages [image: without removing packages that depend on them] (`-Rdd`) and install the 4.10 ones.

For problems related to the packages themselves, you should post comments on the AUR rather than here. You'll have more chance of getting quick answers.

**UPDATE**: a [patch](https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/pull/15) by @pallegro now makes it possible to use the official pyqt4 package. This has not been merged upstream yet, but in the meantime the patch is applied in the appropriate PKGBUILD.

**UPDATE 2**: this is now [officially solved](https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/pull/21).

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0